# Multiple separate forms for searching up different apache solr indexes

Tags: 7, search

Mac_Weber in IRC gave me some great info in relation to this earlier, but I have a more indepth question: is it possible to have multiple separate forms for searching up different apache solr indexes? Say for example I had a separate indexes on rock stars, countries, and organic food suppliers. I want a drupal website that has literaly separate pages with a search box to search upon these indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The the [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) is perfect for the job. This module provides a framework for easily creating searches on any entity known to Drupal, using any kind of search engine (including Solr). You can create multiple indexes with their own individual search pages/blocks and have granular control over what fields are searched and the relevancy.

Comment: Alright, this is pretty awesome. Could this work even if the solr indexes were on an external database? Aka, content not created by Drupal? It sounds like you can, for sure.

Comment: I think the index has to be created by the Search API, but I am not positive.

Comment: A very very good write-up on this here: http://zugec.com/73-how-setup-search-api-apache-solr